# Unable to find and use Android ConstraintLayout as before

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[Where I'm looking for ConstraintLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHYYb.png)

As in the picture, I am unable to look for **ConstraintLayout** dependency there. But when looking through Android Sdk folder, it's there, which is currently 1.0.0-alpha6. This happens after updating to AS Beta, not sure if it was because of that.

**P/S:** Sorry if there's mistake in the way I am asking question, I'm new in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConstraintLayout is now distributed via the SDK Manager -- go to `Tools > Android > SDK Manager` menu item to start it, then click on `SDK Tools`. In the `Support Repository` section you should see an item called "**ConstraintLayout for Android**" -- select it to install it (it will automatically install the solver library).

[image]

Once that's done, you can simply drag a ConstraintLayout from the palette to the design surface:

[image]

This will automatically add the dependency to constraint layout in your build.gradle file. Alternatively, you can also add the dependency manually as you found out :)

Comment: That's not the problem in my case. Everything's fine like you tell me except for the phrase <b>This will automatically add the dependency to constraint layout in your build.gradle file.</b> And I'm doing your alternative suggestion. Thanks for the help anyway. :)

Comment: Which version of studio are you using?

Comment: It's 2.2 Beta 1. Hoping to use it like usual, its not fancy to manually doing that everytime

Comment: If you don't have any dependency in your build.gradle and you drag a ConstraintLayout from the palette, or you create a new layout file with ConstraintLayout as root, it definitely should add the dependency (and propose you to download it if need be). If that doesn't happen, could you please file a bug http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After working on some workarounds, I found out that just by manually adding the following line to module level **build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha6'
```